# Alternative to using CASE in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to find a more compact code form and faster way to execute a query that requires (or at least I think requires) grouping by TWO case statements

I've tried using OVER PARTITION but can't seem to get the desired result

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT LIKE 'YEPPERS%'
        THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END 'YZY',
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 1 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=3
        THEN
            'Q1'
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 4 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=6
        THEN
            'Q2'
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 7 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=9
        THEN
            'Q3'
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 10 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=12
        THEN
            'Q4'
    END 'QTR',
    SUM(POI.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY) PO_QTY
FROM VW_PO_ITEM POI
LEFT JOIN VW_ARTICLE_ATTRIBUTES AA ON AA.ARTICLE = POI.MATERIAL 
WHERE POI.DEL_INDICATOR <> 'L' AND POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE BETWEEN '7/1/2019' AND '12/31/2019' AND ((POI.SHIPPING_INSTRUCT='A2' AND AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT NOT LIKE 'YEPPERS%') OR AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT LIKE 'YEPPERS%')
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT LIKE 'YEPPERS%'
        THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
    END, 
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 1 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=3
        THEN
            'Q1'
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 4 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=6
        THEN
            'Q2'
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 7 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=9
        THEN
            'Q3'
        WHEN MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) >= 10 AND MONTH(POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) <=12
        THEN
            'Q4'
    END
```

```
--desired result (the query above does produce this) 

YZY      QTR  PO_QTY
-------- ---- ---------------------------------------
NO       Q4   389309
YES      Q4   649842
YES      Q3   843438
NO       Q3   20146
```

Comment: show raw data then desired result

Comment: Generally, you avoid repeating big ugly expressions you want to `group by` by adding a layer, for example a CTE: `;WITH x AS (SELECT col = CASE ... <big expression> ... END FROM ...) SELECT col FROM x GROUP BY col;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to handle unit level calculation before final aggregation, avoiding repetition. Also, look into [DatePart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to extract date parts from datetime fields:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT CASE 
               WHEN AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT LIKE 'YEPPERS%' 
               THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
          END [YZY], 
          DATEPART(qq, POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE) AS [QTR], 
          POI.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY
   FROM VW_PO_ITEM POI 
   LEFT JOIN VW_ARTICLE_ATTRIBUTES AA 
       ON AA.ARTICLE = POI.MATERIAL 
   WHERE POI.DEL_INDICATOR <> 'L' 
     AND POI.EX_FACTORY_DATE BETWEEN '2019-07-01' AND '2019-12-31' 
     AND (
          (POI.SHIPPING_INSTRUCT='A2' 
           AND AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT NOT LIKE 'YEPPERS%') 
          OR 
           AA.BUSINESS_SEGMENT LIKE 'YEPPERS%'
         ) 
  ) 

SELECT [YZY], [QTR],
       SUM(POI.PO_ORDERED_QUANTITY) AS PO_QTY 
FROM cte
GROUP BY [YZY], [QTR]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think better is use DATEPART(quarter

```
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(quarter, columndate)
```